# Import jsPDF autoTable plugin to ionic angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to create a pdf in an ionic/angular 4 project. I use jsPDF with jspdf-autotable plugin to create a pdf document by button press.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

doc.autoTable is underlined: [ts] Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'. [2339]
as it is a plugin...

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({head: head, body: body, startY: 80 });
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

How can I add the plugin to jsPDF in ionic/angular?

Comment: import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable'; works but the doc.autoTable is still underlined with the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following"

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
],
```

In your component:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
.
.
.
jsPDF: any; //important
```